# Jquery Check if all Except One Checkbox is Checked

Tags: jquery, forms

I have a set of checkboxes specified by class = "checkbox". I want to check if all checkboxes except the one with id="donotcheck" are checked. How can I alter the following code to do this?

```
$('.checkbox[checked!=true]').length == 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like:

```
var $boxes = $('.checkbox'),
    numberOfCheckedBoxes = $boxes.filter(':checked').length,
    numberOfCheckableBoxes = $boxes.not('#donotcheck').length,
    numberOfUncheckableBoxes = $boxes.filter('#donotcheck:checked').length;

if (numberOfCheckedBoxes === numberOfCheckableBoxes && numberOfUncheckableBoxes === 0) {
    alert ('All good.');
} else {
    alert ('ERROR!');
}
```

Demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/2NcLu/1/

Comment: Your code produces "all good" even when no checkboxes are checked. The topic starter obviously wants "all good" if ALL checkboxes EXCEPT one specified are checked.

Comment: [@BrianG.] Good call. Fixed it.

Comment: Yep. There is probably a more elegant way to do this, but it surely works now.

Answer (score -1):

Try this 
[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/maju/CUAmd/1/)

```
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" />
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" />
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox"  id="donotcheck" />
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" />
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" />

<button id="testButton">test</button>

var testButton = $('#testButton');

testButton.on('click', function() {
    if($(".checkbox:checked:not(#donotcheck)").length ==$(".checkbox:not(#donotcheck)").length && !$("#donotcheck").is(":checked")){
  alert("all Except One Checkbox is Checked");
    } else {
        alert('error...')
    }
});
```

Comment: Still doesn't work. If you check everything, it will still validate: http://jsfiddle.net/CUAmd/

Comment: Still validates with 5 checked boxes ;)

Comment: Ahh forgot to save the changes to the fiddle . Now its updated